# how to get rid of the duplicate timeout exception message from Python's subprocess?

Tags: python, exception, timeout, subprocess, error-messaging

This test code

```
import subprocess
out=subprocess.run(["sleep","10"], timeout=1)
```

generates under Python 3.5.3 the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 385, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 801, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1476, in _communicate
    self.wait(timeout=self._remaining_time(endtime))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1385, in wait
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '['sleep', '10']' timed out after 0.9999505979940295 seconds

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 390, in run
    stderr=stderr)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '['sleep', '10']' timed out after 1 seconds
```

This first of these two exception messages is inappropriate and confusing. It contains internals a normal user of the Python API does not want to see. It suggests there is something wrong *within* subprocess.py although it is expected regular behavior for subprocess to silently handle a timeout imposed by the application programmer.

Is there a way to get a cleaner exception message?

Should I raise this complaint on the Python issue tracker?